# Deleting everything in the folder other than recent ones perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to incorporate a bit of cleaning up to my output directory, in which all the files other the very recent ones are to be deleted.

```
my @files = grep{ -f && -t } glob($outputdir);
349 
350 my @expected_file  = grep { /SequenomComparisonSummary\_(\d+)\.txt/} @files;
351 foreach my $file(@expected_file){
352 
353   unlink $file;
354   warn "Removing file $file\n";
355 }
```

But I want to keep the very recent ones in the directory and delete the rest? Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```perl
unlink $file if -M $file > 7;  # unlink if older than one week
```

(Or you can use `-M > 7` as part of your `grep` condition.)

---

Ps. The `-t` in your `grep` condition is probably not doing what you think it is.  From [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#-X):

> "`-t`  Filehandle is opened to a tty."
>
> "If the argument is omitted, tests `$_`, except for `-t`, which tests STDIN."

So the `-t` in your code is checking whether `STDIN` is a terminal, which I'd assume is not what you really wanted to check.

Comment: Hi Ilmari, Thanks ! nicely spotted It should be T and not -t. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I posted a script on my site to do this carefully (in a Windows environment) and to allow for a dry run.  The script is at http://www.billruppert.com/2009/05/deleting-old-files.html.  It's a bit long to copy here.